# Adding a footer which sticks to the bottom of the page when there isn't much content

Tags: html, css, layout

I am new in Grails and displaying list of users by using list.gsp page but when list have less items say 1 or 2 then footer is appears after two record instead of taking it's fix position at bottom of browser.

I have tried by updating my css in main.css and also applying css to 'g:layoutBody' tag.but result is same.

Any one can please help me how to set footer at bottom.
i am using following css in 'g:layoutBody' tag-

```
<g:layoutBody style="position: fixed;left: 0px;bottom: 30px;width: 100%;"/>
```

my main.css has this code -

```
body {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #333333;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: inherit;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* prevents box-shadow causing a horizontal scrollbar in firefox when viewport < 960px wide */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0.3em #255b17;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0.3em #255b17;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.3em #255b17;
}
```

and footer css is

```
.footer {
    background: #abbf78;
    color: #000;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    padding: 1em;
    min-height: 1em;
 }

.footer a {
    color: #255b17;
 }
```

Comment: please, provide jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a purely HTML/CSS issue, so the same applies for GSPs and standard HTML pages.

What you're after is a "sticky footer", and it can be most easily achieved by wrapping your content in a container which pushes the footer to the bottom of the page.

Here's a working example (updated with content from question): http://jsfiddle.net/spikeheap/ujttV/2/

The key bits are to structure the HTML with something which extends below your content:

```
<body>
   <div class="wrapper">
       <div id="content">
           ...
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="footer">
       This is a footer message
   </div>
</body>
```

Then you can use CSS to set the height of the wrapper to be 100%:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Finally your footer can be clever and pull itself up from below the bottom of the page by using a negative margin-top:

```
.footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #cecece;
}
```

You'll notice pretty quickly that if you make the window really small, or grow your content, that it's truncated, so your content block should have padding equal to the footer height (to make sure it pushes it down when it fills the space:

```
#content {
    padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

#### Update

The `layoutBody` tag is used for rendering the body of your gsp, so you could have layouts/mytemplate.gsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <g:layoutHead />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <g:layoutBody />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        This is a footer message
    </div>
</body>
```

And then in (for example) index.gsp:

```
<head>
  <meta name="layout" content="mytemplate">
</head>
<body>
     Welcome to my website. Check out the amazing footer
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is not working correctly,please try using same code just change  height: 20px; in footer class then footer is move to center of page.One more problem is when list has large number of rows then some of row's are move to below of footer.

Comment: I have updated the JSFiddle to demonstrate it working with your CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/spikeheap/ujttV/2/.

Comment: It sounds like you've not copied and pasted this correctly. The footer will sit at the bottom of the text for long pages (play with the content in the JSFiddle to see it in action). Also the footer is clearly at the bottom of the pane. Maybe you missed setting the height of body to 100%?

Comment: yep!! i was missing #content {
    padding-bottom: 200px;
} these line.thanks

Comment: Excellent, glad it worked. An upvote on the answer would be much appreciated :).

Comment: Almost seven years later and still works like a charm!